# Cheapest/right bypass for Avatel 4111L remote start. DBALL or the 556U?

Tags: ignition, security, installation, by-pass

I'm doing my homework before getting professional installation with mail-order parts.

I want to install a Avatel 4111L in my 2006 Acura TSX.  Avatel (Directed Electronics) Support recommends the Directed Electronics DBALL part as the required bypass.

I'm also seeing a Directed Electronics 556U Universal Bypass which can be had for cheaper.

Will the 556U work just as well without any abnormal hacking?

==============

And I know I said that I was going to get this done professionally, but what would it take for me to install it myself?  I don't particularly trust that the "pros" wouldn't just be learning for the first time on my car too.

I just want the auto start.  If it stays locked while the car is running off the autostart, that's fine with me.  I'd just push the one-button again to stop the car.  Unlock it with factory fob.  Get in.  Start car normally.  (Maybe the car unlocks after "off", not sure).  The other factory security and door features will not change in behavior.  Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This video pretty much answered everything.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mp0gGRFSZR0